# Trouble saving selected values in selectManyListbox

Tags: jsf-2, liferay, selectmanylistbox

We're having some problems with saving the selected values in a `h:selectManyListbox`.

What happens is that only the last value selected gets saved.
I've placed a breakpoint in the components `setValue(List)` method.
When just selecting/deselecting everything seems fine, `setValue` is called, the list of strings it receives as argument is filled with one or more strings. 
But, when pressing our "Save" button the `setValue` method gets called an additional time, this time with the list argument consisting of only ONE element, effectivly overwriting any previous values!

This additional call to `setValue()` occurs before even reaching our save button code.


Our system setup is Liferay 6.1.1 bundle with Tomcat7 with jsf 2.1.
Anyone has a clue what the problem might be ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to declare in your backbean a list like String[] selectedValues?
for example:

```
<h:selectManyListbox value="#{backBean.selectedValues}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="" />
    .....

</h:selectManyListbox>
```

ZTB.